# Rounding of significant figures if less than 1 in R

Tags: r, rounding

I would like to create a function in R that rounds numeric dataframes (or columns in a dataframe) depending on the number. If the number is less than 1, round to 1 decimal, but if it is greater than 1, round to 0 decimals.

This is what I have

```
data <- data.frame(x = c(1.111, 0.809, 5.55555, 0.567), y = c(0.235, 0.777, 4.55555555, 393.55))
round0 <- function(x) format(round(x, digits=0), nsmall = 0, trim = TRUE)
round0(data)
   x   y
1  1   0
2  1   1
3  6   5
4  1 394

# What I want 
   x   y
1  1   0.2
2 0.8  1
3  6   5
4  1 394
```

Answer (score 2):

```
> round0 <- function(x) ifelse(x<1,round(x,1),round(x))
> sapply(data,round0)
       x     y
[1,] 1.0   0.2
[2,] 0.8   0.8
[3,] 6.0   5.0
[4,] 0.6 394.0
```

Comment: Note: R will still display the decimals even if you rounded to 0 decimals, this cannot be avoided... unless you change the type.

Answer (score 1):

You can use :

```
round0 <- function(x) ifelse(x < 1, format(round(x, 1), nsmall = 1), round(x))
data[] <- lapply(data, round0)
data
#    x     y
#1   1   0.2
#2 0.8   0.8
#3   6     5
#4 0.6   394
```

Note that this is only for display purpose and classes of columns are of type character. If you want to perform any mathematical calculation on it you need to convert it back to numeric.